# How to collapse one column whilst aggregating another

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following input data:

```
student:xxxxx
student:yyyyy
student:zzzzz
student:kkkkk
student:.
teacher:aaaaa
teacher:bbbbb
teacher:lllll
teacher:.
student:sssss
student:mmmmm
student:.
```

I need to extract the data to be like this:

```
student:xxxxx yyyyy zzzzz kkkkk.
teacher:aaaaa bbbbb lllll.
student:sssss mmmmm.
```

How can I do this by using `sed` and `awk`

Comment: Is this a real problem or just homework? What have you tried doing?

Comment: its not a homework, a report has generated like that format, i need to convert into single line of all the pattern matched.Help me in this problem.

Comment: r u ok with python?

Comment: please tell me in bash shell or using unix commands

Comment: ok, even python also tell me

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858240/make-the-first-identical-column-into-single-row-of-a-file

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask - "Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs"

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=":" }
{
    if ($2==".") {
        ORS = "\n"
        OFS = ""
        cnt = 0
    }
    else {
        ORS = ""
        OFS = " "
        cnt++
    }
    print (cnt==1 ? $0 : OFS $2)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
student:xxxxx yyyyy zzzzz kkkkk.
teacher:aaaaa bbbbb lllll.
student:sssss mmmmm.
```

If it's not obvious how that works you can research all the constructs used in the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 2):

A `sed` solution:

```
/:\./! { s/^.*://; H }
/:\./  { G; s/\n/ /g; s/\. //; s/$/./p; s/.*//; x }
```